# Unhandled exception error while Initializing directX 11

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, directx-11

When i try to Initialize and directX 11, i get the following error:

## Error:

```
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\JayRavi\Desktop\Directx 11 Tutorials\Engine\Debug\Engine.exe', Symbols loaded.
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dxgi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d11.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3dx10_43.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvinit.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\detoured.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\Nvd3d9wrap.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\nvdxgiwrap.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\Real\RealPlayer\BrowserRecordPlugin\Chrome\Hook\rpchrome150browserrecordhelper.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57\msvcr90.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
First-chance exception at 0x00cb2efe in Engine.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x773315de in Engine.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
The program '[5604] Engine.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005).
```

Of course there is no syntax error. 
OS: Windows 7 Premium 64bit. 
DirectX version: 11(well, duh!)
IDE: Visual Studio 2010(VC++)

## Code:

## "d3dclass.h"

```
        #ifndef _D3DCLASS_H_
        #define _D3DCLASS_H_

        //Linking libraries for direct 3d

        #pragma comment(lib, "dxgi.lib")
        #pragma comment(lib, "d3d11.lib")
        #pragma comment(lib, "d3dx11.lib")
        #pragma comment(lib, "d3dx10.lib")

        #include <dxgi.h>
        #include <D3Dcommon.h>
        #include <d3d11.h>
        #include <D3DX10.h>


        class D3DClass
        {
        public:
            D3DClass();
            D3DClass(const D3DClass&);
            ~D3DClass();

            bool Initialize(int, int, bool, HWND, bool, float,float);
            void Shutdown();

            void BeginScene(float, float, float, float);
            void EndScene();

            ID3D11Device* GetDevice();
            ID3D11DeviceContext* GetDeviceContext();

            void GetProjectionMatrix(D3DXMATRIX&);
            void GetWorldMatrix(D3DXMATRIX&);
            void GetOrthoMatrix(D3DXMATRIX&);

            void GetVideoCardInfo(char*, int&);

        private:
            bool                            m_vsync_enabled;
            int                             m_videoCardMemory;
            char                            m_videoCardDescription[128];
            IDXGISwapChain*                 m_swapChain;
            ID3D11Device*                   m_device;
            ID3D11DeviceContext*            m_deviceContext;
            ID3D11RenderTargetView*         m_renderTargetView;
            ID3D11Texture2D*                m_depthStencilBuffer;
            ID3D11DepthStencilState*        m_depthStencilState;
            ID3D11DepthStencilView*         m_depthStencilView;
            ID3D11RasterizerState*          m_rasterState;
            D3DXMATRIX                      m_projectionMatrix;
            D3DXMATRIX                      m_worldMatrix;
            D3DXMATRIX                      m_orthoMatrix;

        };
        #endif
```

## "d3dclass.cpp"

```
#include "d3dclass.h"

D3DClass::D3DClass()
{
    m_swapChain              = 0;
    m_device                 = 0;
    m_deviceContext          = 0;
    m_renderTargetView       = 0;
    m_depthStencilBuffer     = 0;
    m_depthStencilState      = 0;
    m_depthStencilView       = 0;
    m_rasterState            = 0;
}

D3DClass::D3DClass(const D3DClass& other)
{
}
D3DClass::~D3DClass()
{
}


bool D3DClass::Initialize(int screenWidth, int screenHeight, bool vsync,
                        HWND hwnd, bool fullscreen, float screenDepth, float screenNear)

{
    HRESULT                             result;
    IDXGIFactory*                       factory;
    IDXGIAdapter*                       adapter;
    IDXGIOutput*                        adapterOutput;
    unsigned int                        numModes, i, numerator, denominator, stringLength;
    DXGI_MODE_DESC*                     displayModeList;
    DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC                   adapterDesc;
    int                                 error;
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC                swapChainDesc;
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL                   featureLevel;
    ID3D11Texture2D*                    backBufferPtr;
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC                depthBufferDesc;
    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC            depthStencilDesc;
    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC       depthStencilViewDesc;
    D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC               rasterDesc;
    D3D11_VIEWPORT                      viewport;
    float                               fieldOfView, screenAspect;

    //store the vsync setting.
    m_vsync_enabled = vsync;

    //Create a directX graphics interface factory
    result = CreateDXGIFactory(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory), (void**)&factory);
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }
    //Use the factory to create an adapter for the primary graphics interface(video card).
    result = factory->EnumAdapters(0, &adapter);
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Enumerate the primary adapter output (monitor).
    result = adapter->EnumOutputs(0, &adapterOutput);
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Get the number of modes that fit the DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM display format for the adapter output(monitor).
    result = adapterOutput->GetDisplayModeList(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, DXGI_ENUM_MODES_INTERLACED, &numModes, NULL);
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        return false; 
    }

    //create a list to hold all the possible display modes for this monitor/video card combination
    displayModeList = new DXGI_MODE_DESC[numModes];
    if(!displayModeList)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Now fill the display mode list strutures
    result = adapterOutput->GetDisplayModeList(DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, DXGI_ENUM_MODES_INTERLACED, &numModes, displayModeList);
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Now go through all the display modes and find the one that matches the
    //screen width and height. When a match is found store the numerator and
    //denominator of the refresh rate for that monitor.
    for(i=0; i<numModes; i++)
    {
        if(displayModeList[i].Width == (unsigned int)screenWidth)
        {
            if(displayModeList[i].Height == (unsigned int)screenHeight)
            {
                numerator = displayModeList[i].RefreshRate.Numerator;
                denominator = displayModeList[i].RefreshRate.Denominator;
            }
        }
    }

    //Get the adapter (video card) description
    result = adapter->GetDesc(&adapterDesc);
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Store the dedicated video card memory in megabytes.
    m_videoCardMemory = (int)(adapterDesc.DedicatedVideoMemory / 1024 / 1024);

    //Convert the name of the video card to a character array and store it. 
    error = wcstombs_s(&stringLength, m_videoCardDescription, 128, adapterDesc.Description, 128);
    if(error!=0)
    {
        return false; 
    }

    //Release the display mode list. 
    delete [] displayModeList;
    displayModeList = 0;

    //Release the adapter output. 
    adapterOutput->Release();
    adapterOutput = 0;

    //Release the adapter.
    adapter->Release();
    adapter = 0;

    //Release the factory. 
    factory->Release();
    factory = 0;

    //Initialize the swap chain description. 
    ZeroMemory(&swapChainDesc, sizeof(swapChainDesc));

    //Set to a single back buffer. 
    swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 1;

    //Set the width and height of the back buffer. 
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Width = screenWidth;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Height = screenHeight;

    //Set regular 32Bit surface for the back buffer. 
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;

    //Set the refresh rate of the back buffer. 
    if(m_vsync_enabled)
    {
        swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = numerator;
        swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = denominator;
    }
    else
    {
        swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 0;
        swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
    }

    //Set the usage of the back buffer. 
    swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;

    //set the handle for the window to render to . 
    swapChainDesc.OutputWindow = hwnd;

    //turn multisampling off. 
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;

    //Set to full screen or windowed mode. 
    if(fullscreen)
    {
        swapChainDesc.Windowed = false;
    }
    else
    {
        swapChainDesc.Windowed = true;
    }

    //Set the scan line ordering and scaling to unspecified. 
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
    swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;

    //Discard the back buffer contents after presenting. 
    swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;

    //Dont set the advanced flags. 
    swapChainDesc.Flags = 0;

    //Set the feature level to DirectX 11. 
    featureLevel = D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0;

    //Create the swap chain, Direct 3D device and direct 3d device context. 
    result = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL,0,
                                &featureLevel, 1, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &swapChainDesc, &m_swapChain, &m_device, NULL, &m_deviceContext);

    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Get the pointer to the back buffer. 
    result = m_swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&backBufferPtr);
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Create the render target view with the back buffer pointer. 
    result = m_device->CreateRenderTargetView(backBufferPtr, NULL, &m_renderTargetView);
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        return false; 
    }

    //Release pointer to the back buffer as we no longer need it. 
    backBufferPtr->Release();
    backBufferPtr = 0;

    //Initialize the description of the depth buffer. 
    ZeroMemory(&depthBufferDesc, sizeof(depthBufferDesc));

    //Set up the description of the depth buffer. 
    depthBufferDesc.Width = screenWidth;
    depthBufferDesc.Height = screenHeight;
    depthBufferDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    depthBufferDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    depthBufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
    depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    depthBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    depthBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
    depthBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    depthBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    //Create the texture for the depth buffer using the filled out description. 
    result = m_device->CreateTexture2D(&depthBufferDesc, NULL, &m_depthStencilBuffer);
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Initialize the description of the stencil state. 
    ZeroMemory(&depthStencilDesc, sizeof(depthStencilDesc));

    //Set up the description of the stencil state. 
    depthStencilDesc.DepthEnable = true;
    depthStencilDesc.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
    depthStencilDesc.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS;

    depthStencilDesc.StencilEnable = true;
    depthStencilDesc.StencilReadMask = 0xFF;
    depthStencilDesc.StencilWriteMask = 0xFF;

    //Stencil operations if pixel is front facing. 
    depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_INCR;
    depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

    //Stencil operations if pixel is back-facing.
    depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_DECR;
    depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

    //Create the depth stencil state. 
    result = m_device->CreateDepthStencilState(&depthStencilDesc, &m_depthStencilState);
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Set the depth stencil state. 
    m_deviceContext->OMSetDepthStencilState(m_depthStencilState, 1);

    //Initialize the depth stencil view. 
    ZeroMemory(&depthStencilViewDesc, sizeof(depthStencilViewDesc));

    //Set up the depth Stencil view description. 
    depthStencilViewDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
    depthStencilViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    depthStencilViewDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;

    //Create the depth stencil view. 
    result = m_device->CreateDepthStencilView(m_depthStencilBuffer, &depthStencilViewDesc, &m_depthStencilView);
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Bind the render target view and depth stencil buffer to the output render pipeline. 
    m_deviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &m_renderTargetView, m_depthStencilView);

    //Setup the raster description which will determine how and what polygons will be drawn
    rasterDesc.AntialiasedLineEnable = false;
    rasterDesc.CullMode = D3D11_CULL_BACK;
    rasterDesc.DepthBias = 0;
    rasterDesc.DepthBiasClamp = 0.0f;
    rasterDesc.DepthClipEnable = true;
    rasterDesc.FillMode = D3D11_FILL_SOLID;
    rasterDesc.FrontCounterClockwise = false;
    rasterDesc.MultisampleEnable = false;
    rasterDesc.ScissorEnable = false;
    rasterDesc.SlopeScaledDepthBias = 0.0f;

    //Create the rasterizer state from the description we just filled out. 
    result = m_device->CreateRasterizerState(&rasterDesc, &m_rasterState);
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Now set the rasterizer state. 
    m_deviceContext->RSSetState(m_rasterState);

    //Setup the viewport for rendering. 
    viewport.Width = (float)screenWidth;
    viewport.Height = (float)screenHeight;
    viewport.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    viewport.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
    viewport.TopLeftX = 0.0f;
    viewport.TopLeftY = 0.0f;

    //Create the viewport.
    m_deviceContext->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

    //Setupthe project matrix.
    fieldOfView = (float)D3DX_PI / 4.0f;
    screenAspect = (float)screenWidth / (float)screenHeight;

    //Create the project matrix for 3D rendering. 
    D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&m_projectionMatrix, fieldOfView, screenAspect, screenNear, screenDepth);

    //Initialize the world matrix to the identity matrix. 
    D3DXMatrixIdentity(&m_worldMatrix);

    //Create an orthographic projection matrix for 2D rendering.
    D3DXMatrixOrthoLH(&m_orthoMatrix, (float)screenWidth, (float)screenHeight, screenNear, screenDepth);

    return true;
}

void D3DClass::Shutdown()
{
    //Before shutting down set to windowed mode or when you release the swap chain
    //it will throw an exception

    if(m_swapChain)
    {
        m_swapChain->SetFullscreenState(false,NULL);
    }

    if(m_rasterState)
    {
        m_rasterState->Release();
        m_rasterState = 0;
    }

    if(m_depthStencilView)
    {
        m_depthStencilView->Release();
        m_depthStencilView = 0;
    }

    if(m_depthStencilState)
    {
        m_depthStencilState->Release();
        m_depthStencilState = 0;
    }

    if(m_depthStencilBuffer)
    {
        m_depthStencilBuffer->Release();
        m_depthStencilBuffer = 0;
    }

    if(m_renderTargetView)
    {
        m_renderTargetView->Release();
        m_renderTargetView = 0;
    }

    if(m_deviceContext)
    {
        m_deviceContext->Release();
        m_deviceContext = 0;
    }

    if(m_device)
    {
        m_device->Release();
        m_device = 0;
    }

    if(m_swapChain)
    {
        m_swapChain->Release();
        m_swapChain = 0;
    }

    return;
}

void D3DClass::BeginScene(float red, float green, float blue, float alpha)
{
    float color[4];

    //setup the color to clear the buffer to. 
    color[0] = red;
    color[1] = green;
    color[2] = blue;
    color[3] = alpha;

    //Clear the back buffer
    m_deviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView(m_renderTargetView, color);

    //Clear the depth buffer
    m_deviceContext->ClearDepthStencilView(m_depthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0);

    return;
}

void D3DClass::EndScene()
{
    //present the back buffer to the screen since rendering is complete
    if(m_vsync_enabled)
    {
        //Lock to screen refresh rate
        m_swapChain->Present(1,0);
    }
    else
    {
        //Present as fast as possible.
        m_swapChain->Present(0,0);
    }

    return;
}

ID3D11Device* D3DClass::GetDevice()
{
    return m_device;
}

ID3D11DeviceContext* D3DClass::GetDeviceContext()
{
    return m_deviceContext;
}

void D3DClass::GetProjectionMatrix(D3DXMATRIX& projectionMatrix)
{
    projectionMatrix = m_projectionMatrix;
    return;
}

void D3DClass::GetWorldMatrix(D3DXMATRIX& worldMatrix)
{
    worldMatrix = m_worldMatrix;
    return;
}

void D3DClass::GetOrthoMatrix(D3DXMATRIX& orthoMatrix)
{
    orthoMatrix = m_orthoMatrix;
    return;
}

void D3DClass::GetVideoCardInfo(char* cardName, int& memory)
{
    strcpy_s(cardName, 128, m_videoCardDescription);
    memory = m_videoCardMemory;
    return;
}
```

A little update:
i have a variable(pointer) called m_D3D that is declared from another file called graphics.cpp. Error occurs when the constructor is called in D3DClass to initialize all the vars to 0(NULL). When i checked the value of m_D3D at this pointer i found the following message:

m_D3D    CXX0017: Error: symbol "" not found

Please advise.

Cheers

Comment: Something is wrong in your code... without seeing that there is no chance anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: Well i thought it would be too huge to paste it here. but anyways, its up.

Answer (score 1):

Compile as debug version, run in IDE. It'll show you where the error occurred.

(`msvcr90.dll` tells me you're running a release build).

Comment: you were right, i was running in retail mode. but after switching to debug version, im still getting the same exception.

Comment: I'd expected as much, that's the premise of debug mode. But now your debugger should show you the cause of that exception.

Comment: if u look at my original post, i have appended at little update. there is something going wrong after the constructor of d3dclass is called while initializing the m_D3D pointer.

Comment: Well, no. The message you show (`m_D3D` symbol not found) makes perfect sense. The variable `m_D3D` doesn't exist in the scope of d3dclass.cpp

Comment: its like this. graphics.h has a class called graphicsClass which has all the method prototypes and member vars declared. so m_D3D is declared like
private:
D3DClass* m_D3D;
now in graphics.cpp:
i create a new D3DClass object by doing this:
m_D3D = new D3DClass;
after this statement i get the exception error.

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering if you included the lib and include directories correctly into visual studio? [rastertek](http://rastertek.com/dx11tut01.html) has a nice walkthrough in case something is wrong.

Hope this helps.